# Work performed by ramping of magnetic field (non-interacting Ising model)

Tags: thermodynamics, ising-model, non-equilibrium

Consider the following hamiltonian

$$H=-h\sum_{i=1}^N\sigma_i$$

where $\sigma_i=\pm1$ and $h$ is the magnetization.

Let us assume that the system is equilibrated with a bath at temperature $T$ with $h=0$. Then the field is ramped up to $h=h_0$, and the system equilibrate again with a bath at temperature $T$.

what is the work performed in this process?

Comment: Your use of the word “equilibrate” is very unclear to me. Do you perhaps mean: “put into thermal equilibrium with...” and “the system in equilibrium” resp. instead?

Comment: @Antaios. the system equilibrate again with a bath at temperture $T$. corrected in the post.

Answer (score 1):

By work, I presume you mean *macroscopic work*. This is the work done by an external agent in sustaining a magnetic field $h_0$ until a Magnetisation $M$ is induced.

Macroscopic work done in changing the magnetisation from $0$ to $M$ is given by a by the expression(See Heat and Thermodynamics, Zemansky and Dittman, Seventh Edition, Eq 3.11):
$$W=\int_0^M hdM$$
Assuming the field is flipped to $h_0$ *instantaneously* 
$$W=h_0\int_0^M dM=h_0 M$$
This is numerically equal to the average energy with a negative sign.
This is a standard exercise in statistical mechanics that requires the definition of a partition function:
$$Z=2^Ncosh^N \beta h_0$$
Where $\beta=\frac{1}{KT}$.

Average Energy is given by:
$$U=-\frac{\partial \log Z}{\partial \beta}$$